# L2 機器はどうやって Ethernet (DIX) フレームの終わりの誤動作を防いでいる?

Tags: network

[Wikipedia の Ethernet のページ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Header)を読んでいました。そこに、以下のような記述がありました。

> When used as EtherType, the length of the frame is determined by the location of the interpacket gap and valid frame check sequence (FCS).

つまり、 DIX 方式の Ethernet では、そのフレームの長さは interpacket gap と FCS によって決定される、と書いてあります。 interpacket gap は、自分のなんとなくの想像ですが、おそらく 0 埋めのデータが続くことをもって gap と呼んでいるのだろう、と思っています。

ここでふと、例えば UDP など任意のデータを送れるプロトコルで、有効な FCS と 0 埋めフィールドが UDP payload の中間に出現するようなデータを送信することになった場合、この形式だと L2 機器は Ethernet Frame の終わりを勘違いして動作したりしないのだろうか、と疑問が生じました。

## 質問

上記の通り、 interpacket gap と FCS の要件を(偶然)満たすような payload を上位プロトコルが指定した場合に、 L2 機器は誤動作をおこしますか? おこさない場合、どのような機構でこれは回避されていますか? もしくは、自分は何か思い違いをしていますでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpacket gapは、無信号(データが何も送られてこない)期間の事です。どのぐらいの期間（時間）信号が無いとInterpacket gapと判断するかは、ethernetの種類によって異なります。
一番遅い10MbpsのEthernetだと9.8マイクロ秒、一番早い400GbpsのGigabit Ethernetだと0.24ナノ秒、などというように。

データ（payload）は、ビット列のまま送られるのではなく、0が続いて送られないように符号化されたものが送られます。
そのため、payload中にinterpacket gapと間違われるような連続した0は存在しません。

(OP追記@2020/11/05)

例えば、 [物理層 - プログラミング探して！](https://program.sagasite.info/wiki/index.php?%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E5%B1%A4#zdfb097d) より、

> #### PCS
>
> 100BASE-TXは、4bitの2値（Binary）信号を、5bit長のパターンに置換する4B／5B符号を利用します（BはBinaryの意味）。さらに、特殊な5bitパターンでフレーム先頭や終端の目印を付け、次のフレームを送信するまでの空隙（IFG：インターフレームギャップ）をアイドルパターンで埋め尽くします。

Comment: 実際に payload は符号化されていたとすると、その符号化は、おそらくですが、OSI でいう L2 以上の規格たちのどこかで定義されているのでは、と思っています。たとえば TCP/IP において、その Ethernet 以上の規格たちの中で、この符号化に相当する記述をまだ見つけられておらず、どこで規定されているのだろうか、と思っているなうです。

Comment: 4B5Bとかの符号化は、物理層(L1)で使われます。https://program.sagasite.info/wiki/index.php?%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E5%B1%A4
のページなどが参考になると思います。

Comment: なるほど、 L1 のレイヤーで interpacket gap と Ethernet Frame (物理層にとっての payload) がまざらないように符号化されるのだ、という理解を得ました。